# Quotient of a $\mathbb Q$-vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, quotient-spaces

Let $f: A \to B$ be an injective map. Then we have a short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to coker(f) \to 0 $ where $coker(f)= B/Im(f)$ and $A,B$  are $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces. Is $coker(f)$ a free module?

I know that $A,B$ are free as they are $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces. But I can't argue that $coker(f)$ is free... I need some help...

Comment: coker$(f)$ is by definition a (free) vector space, the quotient space $B/$Im$(f)$.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are what? Vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$? Is $f$ a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map, just a group homomorphism...? If $f$ is a linear map then $\operatorname{coker}(f)$ is clearly a vector space again, so free...

Comment: Yes $f$ is a $Q$-linear map..